# Inheriting an OpenCV class from OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, binding

I am working on the Tracking algorithms in OpenCV, where the tracking algorithms are inheriting the super class [Tracker](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html). I know that OpenCV is implemented in C++ and [OpenCV-Python uses binding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html) with the C++ implementation.

Without modifying the C++ code, can I simply create another Python class (a different Tracker algoritihm) and inherit the Tracker class? For example, can I simply do something like code given below?

```
import cv2
video_source = '/video/%04d.png'

class MyNewTracker(cv2.Tracker):

    def test(self):  
        print("My test function") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
    bbox = (648, 584, 69, 200)
    ok, frame = video.read()
    tracker = MyNewTracker()
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
```

Edit: When I actually run the code above, I don't get any syntax error or undeclared function or anything like that. However, I do get the good old "***Segmentation fault (core dump)***" error. Is this a sign that the inheritance works, but I am misusing the functions inside the super class Tracker.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @CristiFati I used the code in the question and didn't get any errors. However, I haven't implemented anything yet (Maybe integrate an existing tracker that is not in OpenCV). I want to make sure if this is a dead end or not, and also I want to know if I have to do all my modifications in C++ in OpenCV.

Comment: @CristiFati I edited the question to provide a better understanding to my question.

Comment: Hmm strange, on *Win*, *cv2* (*v4.1.2*), there is no *Tracker*.

Comment: I think it still exist in v4.1.2 and the following versions. https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html

Comment: Oh maybe, it might be in the opencv-contrib?

Comment: No, I meant in the list exported by *cv2* (*Python* package).